# Is there ways to convert WebkitFormBoundary to YAML Swagger/OpenAPI?

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

How to transform below to Swagger/OpenAPI YAML?

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"
    
This is a picture of me
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### OpenAPI 3.0.x

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

paths:
  /something:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              # required: [image, text]  # TODO: Specify which fields are required
              properties:
                image:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                text:
                  type: string
      responses:
        ...
```

More info: [Multipart Requests](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/) on swagger.io

#### OpenAPI 2.0

In OpenAPI 2.0, individual form fields are defined as `in: formData` parameters. The operation also need to have `consumes: [multipart/form-data]`. More info: [File Upload](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/) on swagger.io.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

paths:
  /something:
    post:
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: image
          type: file
          # required: true   # Uncomment if the "image" field is required
        - in: formData
          name: text
          type: string
          # required: true   # Uncomment if the "text" field is required
      responses:
        ...
```